# Add (addsubview) custom/reusable view from XIB OS X App

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

Here is the code for my custom view. I also have a custom XIB file with the view `mainView` in it. I need to use this 3 times in a stackView in a view controller. How do I do that?

```
class PlatformView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentPriceLabel: NSTextField!

    //Here is the button
    @IBAction func testButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        // Drawing code here.
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "PlatformView"), bundle: nil)?.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)
        addSubview(mainView)
        self.mainView.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my mainViewController

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var platformStackView: NSStackView!

    var platformView1:PlatformView!
    var platformView2:PlatformView!
    var platformView3:PlatformView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //This part is not working in a macOS app
        if let tempView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: "PlatformView"), owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)?.first as? PlatformView {
            self.platformView1 = tempView
            self.platformView1.currentPriceLabel = "$1.35"
            self.platformStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.platformView1)
            self.platformStackView.addSubview()
            self.platformStackView.addView(tempView, in: self)
            //Which one of these three methods should I use?

        }
    }
}
```

I have buttons in the Platform View which I would like to connect via IBAction outlets. How would I handle those?

I also added three ways to add a view to stack view. Which one is best to use?

It also says that `.loadNibNamed` will return a Bool not a instance of a view. How do I load the view multiple times in this View controller? I obviously also need to make changes through the life of the VC so I need to keep the instance of that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use:

```
self.platformStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.platformView1)
```

because this will add self.platformView1 as both a sub view (as per `addSubView`) and add it to the list of views the stack view arranges.

Second the XIB file can contain multiple top level objects so can't expect it to return a single object.  The Bool return indicates if the XIB file as a whole was successfully loaded and the contents of the top level objects will be put in the topLevelObjects parameter which is an array.

So you do something like this:

```
var topLevelObjects: NSArray?
if Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: "TestView"), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects) {
    // Use the objects as you need including searching for a specific one you may require.
}
```

As an alternative you can also do this:

```
if let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "TestView"), bundle: nil) {
    if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &temp) {
        // Use the objects as you need including searching for a specific one you may require.
    }
}
```

When used this is the result:
[image]

Here is a worked example of loading a custom class from a XIB file and adding it to the current view controllers view three times.  The button action will load the XIB file instantiate three copies of it and add the TestView class it finds to the view controllers main view (at 0, 110 & 220):

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    var objectArray: NSArray?
    if let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "TestView"), bundle: nil) {
        if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &objectArray),
            let topLevelObjects = objectArray {
            for object in topLevelObjects {
                if let testView = object as? TestView {
                    self.view.addSubview(testView)
                    testView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
                    testView.testLabel.stringValue = "Test Label 1"
                }
            }
        }

        if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &objectArray),
            let topLevelObjects = objectArray {
            for object in topLevelObjects {
                if let testView = object as? TestView {
                    self.view.addSubview(testView)
                    testView.frame = CGRect(x: 110, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
                    testView.testLabel.stringValue = "Test Label 2"
                }
            }
        }

        if nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &objectArray),
            let topLevelObjects = objectArray {
            for object in topLevelObjects {
                if let testView = object as? TestView {
                    self.view.addSubview(testView)
                    testView.frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
                    testView.testLabel.stringValue = "Test Label 3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The TestView code looks like this:

```
class TestView: NSView {
    @IBOutlet var testLabel: NSTextField!

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.testLabel.stringValue = "Init"
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }
}
```

Nothing too complex with that custom view.  It has a single NSTextField which is all setup correctly and so can just have it's string value set.

That all works for me so should be the way to go (this is the first MacOS app I have actually done as I am normally an iOS guy).

Comment: I am getting this error `Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray?' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>?'`

Comment: I got it to build but it is still crashing here `NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "PlatformView"), bundle: nil)?.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)` What is the purpose of the `&`?

Comment: The '&' is require because you need to pass the address pointer of the property not the property itself.  That array will then be populated with the list of objects in the XIB file.  If you don't have it you get the conversion error.  What is the crash you are getting with the second version?

Comment: I just added an image with the crash I am getting

Comment: sorry I added it to your answer by mistake. I meant to add it to my question

Comment: Not a problem.  I assume this also happens after a short delay.  The problem is you are instantiating the XIB inside your custom class itself and you don't need to do that.  In effect you are loading from the XIB and then that class loads from the XIB and then that class loads from the XIB and so on...  The crash you get is because eventually you exhaust the resources available to the app.  You only need to load the XIB once outside of your custom class and then decide what to do with it.

Comment: perfect. so how would I do that? I feel like this is a pretty simple task but it is much harder than I expected it to be. I simply just have a custom view that I want to reuse multiple times in the same window. Do you know what the best way to do that would be? The only requirement I have is that I need that custom view to be built using storyboards and there are buttons and a lot of elements in that view that should be connected through outlets.

Comment: Hang on I will update the answer with a worked example.

Comment: that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: awesome and how would I handle ibaction outlets?

Comment: If you mean in the custom class then they will work as they should and call the appropriate methods within the custom class.

Comment: when I am using the method you described above, I am getting a crash sometimes. Basically, sometimes, the view is coming up as nil. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I also modified your code slightly to make it a little cleaner. I will make an edit to your post to show you. Then you can see if my modification is causing the issue.